# Calculate week numbers for months through excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My week starts from Saturday to Friday and I need to count no of Weeks. E.g. Week starting from `27th Oct 2018` to `2nd Nov 2018` should be counted as first week of month November but formula is calculating it as Week 5 of October month. Below is the formula I have been using.

```
=IF(K89="No Date","No Week",CONCAT("Week ",WEEKNUM(I89-1)-WEEKNUM(I89-DAY(I89)-6)))
```

where `K89` is a date column.

Any suggestions, please.

Comment: You may want to add the excel-formula tag. This will help in getting the right people to look at your problem.

Comment: Applying the formula on end date will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

As found elsewhere:

```
=INT((A2-LOOKUP(A2,DATE(YEAR(A2)-{2,1,0},2,27)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2)-{2,1,0},2,27-7))+7))/7)+1
```

You'll need to change the your desired start date (2,27 for february 27 in this example)

Comment: Actually, I don't have table to lookup. However I need to figure out the week of that particular month based upon given date. e.g. 27th Oct 2018, Saturday to 2nd Nov 2018, Friday should be Week 1 of month November. If I enter date as 27th Oct 2018 then week should come as Week 1 but with the formula it is coming as Week 5, which is not accurate as per my requirement.

Comment: Did you change the date in 2 places? It gives 1 for me.
With 31th Oct 2018 in cell A2 if you use the following formula it will give you 1:
=INT((A2-LOOKUP(A2,DATE(YEAR(A2)-{2,1,0},10,27)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2)-{2,1,0},10,27-7))+7))/7)+1